# Change css animation duration with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to change the speed of an animation in CSS based on a jQuery variable.

```
<div class="elements">
    <div style="background: #000"></div>
    <div style="background: #f90"></div>
    <div style="background: #fff"></div>
</div>
```

Dinamically, I change the animation:

```
sliderElement = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
$('.gears div').removeClass().addClass('animate_' + sliderElement);
```

The problem is the animation looks the same each time whereas the class has been changed successfully.

```
.elements div.animate_0 { animation: animated 0s linear infinite; }
.elements div.animate_1 { animation: animated 2s linear infinite; }
.elements div.animate_2 { animation: animated 6s linear infinite; }
.elements div.animate_3 { animation: animated 10s linear infinite; }

@keyframes animated { 100% { transform:rotate(360deg); } }
```

Why ?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to create an example, and it's work. You can see it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-nightingale-3l6tb)
Probably it was just a typo in selector, not "gears" but "elements"

```js
$(".elements div")
    .removeClass()
    .addClass("animate_" + sliderElement);
```